# Filtrar resultado por data

Tags: mysql

Meu problema é, quando executo o comando abaixo:

```
SELECT Id_produto AS Produto, Quantidade AS quantidade,
genius.vendas.data_venda AS Periodo
FROM genius.itens_venda
LEFT JOIN genius.vendas ON vendas.Id = Id_venda
WHERE `Id_produto` = 3418;
```

Eu tenho como retorno o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

mas quando executo este:

```
SELECT Id_produto AS Produto, Quantidade AS quantidade,
genius.vendas.data_venda AS Periodo
FROM genius.itens_venda
LEFT JOIN genius.vendas ON vendas.Id = Id_venda
WHERE `Id_produto` = 3418 AND `data_venda` BETWEEN 2015-02-23 AND 2015-02-26;
```

o MySQL não me retorna valor nenhum, só a tabela vazia com o nome das colunas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

alguém tem uma solução? e eu preciso também somar a quantidade

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas respostas, eu descobri o que estava errado tentando a solução que vocês propuseram, faltava as aspas da data.
O que mais da raiva em TI kkkkk

Comment: Não é necessário escrever uma resposta apenas pra dizer "obrigado". A melhor maneira de agradecer é **[aceitando](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** a resposta que te ajudou. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/78017)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode tentar especificando a data e hora:

```
SELECT Id_produto AS Produto, Quantidade AS quantidade,
genius.vendas.data_venda AS Periodo
FROM genius.itens_venda
LEFT JOIN genius.vendas ON vendas.Id = Id_venda
WHERE `Id_produto` = 3418 AND 
`data_venda` BETWEEN "2015-02-23 00:00:00" AND "2015-02-26 23:59:59";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE `Id_produto` = 3418 AND (`data_venda` BETWEEN 2015-02-23 AND 2015-02-26);
```

não resolveria?